# Android: SoapObject replace a property value

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

In one of my project i am using `ksoap2` library.

I have to find a way to update value for a particular key that was already added to the `SoapObject`, either by

a) Removing the key/value from the `SoapObject` and adding the key again with the new value

or

b) Updating the value of existing key

For example, I have the `SoapObject` similar to below data,

SaveXXXXRecord{ReferenceNo=TP002011; ReportDateTime=2016-02-29 12:13; Notes=test; TokenID=2760dad08feb5c8b553ad02c; }

I have to replace the value of `TokenID` with a new value.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to update a value in a SoapObject,

```
   private synchronized static void updateProperty(SoapObject request,
                                                String name, String value) {
    try {
        for(int i=0; i < request.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
            PropertyInfo piData = new PropertyInfo();
            request.getPropertyInfo(i, piData);
            if (CommonFunctions.ifStringsSame(name, piData.name)) {
                piData.setValue(value);
                request.setProperty(i, piData.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
            ExceptionHelper.HandleException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: why did you write request.addProperty(name,value);

Comment: Thanks for catching that, That was a mistake. I have updated my answer. The updated one is from my latest code. Thanks